# url valid but view not loading

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've been working on an online learning website for a school project. I've had trouble passing variales when clicking on a lesson, belonging to a section, inside a course. The idea is that on a course page (formation.html.twig), there's a summary of the course, and you can click on the lessons which are in a sidebar menu. It should then display a page with the same menu, and the content of the lesson showing in place of the course summary (lesson.html.twig).

I've updated the controller so the url goes:
formations/consulter-formationid-sectionid-lessonid

In the view, I wrote {{ path('app_formations_lesson',  {'formation':formation.id, 'section': section.id, 'id':lesson.id}) }}

It's working alright for the url and the right values show when I click, but the page refreshes and  won't load the right twig view (lesson.html.twig), it loads the same view I'm currently on (formation.html.twig).

FormationsController:

```
#[Route('/formations/consulter-{id}', name: 'app_formations_see')]
    public function see($id): Response
    {
        $formation = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Formation::class)->findOneById($id);
        $section  = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Section::class)->findAll();
        $lesson = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Lesson::class)->findAll();
        return $this->render('formations/formation.html.twig', [
            'formation' => $formation,
            'sections' => $section,
            'lessons' => $lesson
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/formations/consulter-{formation}-{section}-{id}', name: 'app_formations_lesson')]
    public function seeLesson($id): Response
    {
        $lesson = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Lesson::class)->findOneById($id);
        return $this->render('formations/lesson.html.twig', [
            'lesson' => $lesson
        ]);
    }
```

formation.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}{{ formation.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="formationcontainer text-center">
    {% block sidebar %}
        {% include "./formations/sidebar.html.twig" %}
    {% endblock %}
        <h1>{{ formation.title }} par {{ formation.user.firstname }} {{ formation.user.lastname }}</h1>
        {{ formation.description }}
        <hr>
        <h2>Sommaire</h2>
        <div class="tableau">
            <table class="table">
                {% for section in formation.sections %}
                    <thead class="table-success">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">{{ section.name }}</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for lesson in section.lessons %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ lesson.title }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

lesson.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}titre de la leçon{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="formationcontainer text-center">
        {% block sidebar %}
            {% include "./formations/sidebar.html.twig" %}
        {% endblock %}

        <h1>Nom de la leçon</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>Vidéo</h2>
        <h2>Contenu</h2>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

sidebar block

```
<!-- Sidear for lesson pages -->

<nav class="flex-shrink-0flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-white sidenav">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="sidenav-btn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sidebarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Sommaire
    </button>
    <div class="list-unstyled ps-0 ul-custom navbar-collapse collapse show" id="sidebarCollapse" aria-expanded="true">
        <li class="mb-1">
            {% for section in formation.sections %}
                <ul class="list-unstyled align-items-center rounded fw-normal">
                    <li>{{ section.name }}</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    {% for lesson in lessons %}
                        <ul class="list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                            <li><a href="{{ path('app_formations_lesson',  {'formation':formation.id, 'section': section.id, 'id':lesson.id}) }}" class="link-dark rounded">{{ lesson.title }}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
        <li class="mb-1">
            <ul class="list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                <li><a href="{{path('app_formations')}}" class="link-dark rounded">retour à la liste des formations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Where does this issue come from? How can I display the right view?
Thanks a lot!

edit: I swapped the code in the controller to match the seeLesson function first.

```
#[Route('/formations/consulter-{formation}-{section}-{id}', name: 'app_formations_lesson')]
    public function seeLesson($id): Response
    {
        $formation = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Formation::class)->findOneById($id);
        $section  = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Section::class)->findAll();
        $lesson = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Lesson::class)->findOneById($id);
        return $this->render('formations/lesson.html.twig', [
            'lesson' => $lesson,
            'formation' => $formation,
            'sections' => $section
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/formations/consulter-{id}', name: 'app_formations_see')]
    public function see($id): Response
    {
        $formation = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Formation::class)->findOneById($id);
        $section  = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Section::class)->findAll();
        $lesson = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Lesson::class)->findAll();
        return $this->render('formations/formation.html.twig', [
            'formation' => $formation,
            'sections' => $section,
            'lessons' => $lesson
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you dump something in you seeLessons method using `dump("test"); die();`  ?

If that does nothing, change `/formations/consulter-{formation}-{section}-{id}` to `/formations/consulter_lecon/{formation}/{section}/{id}`

Do not forget to remove the cache

Comment: Swapping functions see and seeLesson seems to have worked, but I'm now getting a null variable error on the sidebar code line 9, seems like I need to pass the sections variable but how should I do it? in the controller? I edited the initial message to add the code I changed.

Comment: Why your loop is `{% for section in formation.sections %}` and not `{% for section in sections %}` ? You return `sections` variable directly from the controller

Comment: If I do that, I'll get all existing sections in the database and I only want to display sections belonging to the formation you're viewing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rendering the wrong page because your URLs are too similar.

When trying to determine what method to execute, Symfony matches the requested URL against the route definitions above the controller methods from top to bottom.

If you're requesting for example `/formations/consulter-1-2-3`,
Symfony first tries to match this against `/formations/consulter-{id}`.
This matches if you substitute `1-2-3` for `{id}`, so it executes the `see` method.

To fix you have two options:

Either switch the order of the 2 methods in your controller so that the method `seeLesson` is defined above the `see` method. Symfony will then first try to match against the route for the `seeLesson` method.

Or keep the method order as is, but add a constraint to the `{id}` parameter in the route for the `see` method, to specify that the matched `{id}` can only consist of digits:

`#[Route('/formations/consulter-{id}', name: 'app_formations_see', requirements: ['id' => '\d+'])]`

Comment: Hi! it seems to be working, but I'm now getting an error saying "Impossible to access an attribute ("sections") on a null variable", which targets the sidebar code line 9 "{% for section in formation.sections %}", I'll edit the initial question to add the modified version of the controller

Comment: I think you need to change this `{% for section in formation.sections %}` to `{% for section in sections %}`?

Comment: I managed to get the view when putting for lesson in lesson and for section in sections, except it makes the sidemenu show all existing sections and lessons in the database, and I only want to display sections and lessons belonging to the formation you're viewing, hence formation.sections, which works. The error is now:
Neither the property "lesson" nor one of the methods "lesson()", "getlesson()"/"islesson()"/"haslesson()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

On line 14 : {% for lesson in formation.sections.lesson %}

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. You're using the lesson id to query for the $formation in `seeLesson`. Keep the formation.sections in twig, but change your controller method to use the formation parameter:

`public function seeLesson($formation, $id): Response {
 $formation = $this->doctrine->getRepository(Formation::class)->findOneById($formation);`

Comment: I think I get the idea, but I still get the same error, I tried emptying the cache and all, I get the same error on the same line

Comment: If you add `dd($formation);` to `seeLesson`, just before the `return render...`, does it show a formation object?

Comment: Ah!! I finally found a fix, it was a pretty dumb semantics issue. Sections and lessons needed to be plural, because that's how they are set up in the entities they're linked to, only formation needs to be singular. I edited all mentions in both the views and controller to make everything plural and it works!! I feel pretty dumb, thanks for your help tho!