# Why is this routing mismatched?

Tags: symfony, routes

A page contains this route: `<a href={{ path('app_gut_food_vector') }}>` but triggers a `not found by the @ParamConverter annotation` error. The log shows this: `Matched route "app_gut_show".` . I cannot figure out how this could be. My question: How to get the correct route matched?

Pieces of the puzzle:

log entry:

```
INFO 23:53:50   request     Matched route "app_gut_show".

{
    "route": "app_gut_show",
    "route_parameters": {
        "_route": "app_gut_show",
        "_controller": "App\\Controller\\GutController::show",
        "id": "vector"
    },
    "request_uri": "http://diet/gut/vector",
    "method": "GET"
}
```

template includes:

```
Click <a href={{ path('app_gut_food_vector') }}> here</a>
```

Controller includes:

```
    #[Route('/vector', name: 'app_gut_food_vector', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function vector(Request $request, GutRepository $gutRepository, VectorService $vectorSvc)
    {
        ...
    }
```

`debug:router` includes:

```
  app_gut_index         GET        ANY      ANY    /gut/                              
  app_gut_new           GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /gut/new                           
  app_gut_show          GET        ANY      ANY    /gut/{id}                          
  app_gut_edit          GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /gut/{id}/edit                     
  app_gut_delete        POST       ANY      ANY    /gut/{id}                          
  app_gut_food_vector   ANY        ANY      ANY    /gut/vector
```

and the incorrectly matched route:

```
    #[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_gut_show', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(Gut $gut): Response
    {
        ...
    }
```

Note: removing the methods from the `vector` method does NOT prevent the mismatch.

Comment: I suspect it is using the string `vector` in the url `/gut/vector` as the `{id}` part for the `app_gut_show` route. Either specify on the `app_gut_show` route that `{id}` needs to be a number, or move the `app_gut_food_vector` method up in your file so that it is before the `app_gut_show` method, to change the order of the url matching. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857481/url-valid-but-view-not-loading/71858260#71858260

Comment: This is precisely the reason for the mismatch. Something I'd not had to deal with before. Modifying show route to `{id<\d+>}` was the fix. Write this up as an answer & I'll accept it. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what symfony version you use, you could try to define route priority.

If you use older version than 5.1, try to move your annotaion to yaml file and define `/gut/vector` route higher than `/gut/{id}` route

For higher version [view Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're somehow messing with route orders.

As a matter of fact `/gut/vector` matches also `/gut/{id}` as regex are used to match routes.

I think you should declare your routes (so controller methods) in other order to avoid this kind of collisions.

Alternatively you can ask esplicitly for `id` to be an integer (if it is an integer; if it is a UUID, just to pick one random example, you should stick to UUID format).